# DispacherTimer, Count up, visible in 00:00:00 Format in textbox Windows Phone

Tags: timer, textbox, count

How to make format like this hh:mm:ss ? ?
Im really tired of getting this up : ) i hope You help me someone.

```
public void StartTimer()
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer myDispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        myDispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100); // 100 Milliseconds 
        myDispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Each_Tick);
        myDispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
    int i = 0;

    // Raised every 100 miliseconds while the DispatcherTimer is active.
    public void Each_Tick(object o, EventArgs sender)
    {
        textBox2.Text = " " + i++.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use TimeSpan as you created above.
Just use `string` formatting function like this:

TimeSpan hundredMilliSec = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,100);

```
textBox2.Text = string.Format(@"{0:hh\:mm\:ss}", hundredMilliSec);
```

Hope this helps.